# Private, instance based, efficient functions | Execution time required

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript language does not directly support classes or class-based inheritance.

However, there are numerous implementations of classes in JavaScript.

All implementations I've seen require the use of self invoking functions to create private, instance-based, efficient functions.

A function has privacy

```
var foo = function(){ /* private to foo here */ };
```

but if you prototype off of it you now have public, instance-based, efficient members.

```
foo.prototype.func = function(){ /* private to func */ }; // foo.func in public now.
```

if you place a function in foo like this

```
var foo = function() { 
    var funcInner = function(){}; 
}; // funcInner is now re-defined in each call to foo.  In-efficient.
```

you get the missing privacy but now there are in-efficiencies.

Hence, the only way to have private, instance based, efficient functions is to use the module pattern ( or similar self invoking pattern ) as such

```
    var NS = (function(){ 
    var private = function(){ /* code */ }; // only created once b.c. in module pattern.
    var publik = {};
        publik.funcPublic = function(){ /* code */ };
    return publik;
})();
```

**Calling**

```
NS.funcPublic();
```

From this it seems that to have private, instance based, efficient functions, a small amount of execution time will be necessary?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module pattern as you presented it is not a good solution. It returns an object `publik`, but most likely you'd like to simulate a class, right? So I guess that you intend to use the `new` operator to create new instances of type `publik`. That does not work with objects, so you would need to call this anonymous function whenever you'd like to create a new instance - and you'd end up with a new private function per instance. (not sure if this is understandable, please ask if you need clarification!)

I have to offer a solution that works pretty good in reality:

```
var Car = (function() {
    // Private functions as local variables:
    var privateFunc = function(self) {};        

    // Create a local variable that will be the class (a function, to
    // enable the "new" keyword.
    var Car = function() {};

    // Attach public methods to the prototype! That's the most efficient way.
    Car.prototype.publicFunc = function() {
        privateFunc(this); // the private functions needs probably
                           // to know about the current instance
    };

    // Now return only the completed "class", to get it out into the wild
    return Car;
})();

var bmw = new Car();
bmw.publicFunc();
```

Comment: Currently, you don't make any use of the object that the anonymous self-executing function returns. Thus, the answer is no. But if you store the returned object in a variable: `var p = (function() ...)();`, p contains an object with exactly one property which is named "funcPublic" - so `p.funcPublic();` would work, yes. That's a good pattern if you only need a single "instance".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. Is it about keeping things private within an object created from a immediately invoked function (iif)? Then would this be something you meant?

```
var x = (function(){ 
    var n = 1;                                          //n = private
    var getSetN = function(val){ n+=val||0; return n; } // getSetN = private
    var public = function(){};
    public.prototype.getset = function(val){ return getSetN(val||0); };
    return public;
}());
var y = new x; z = new x;
y.getset(1);  //=> 2
y.getset(5);  //=> 7
z.getset(1);  //=> 8
y.getset();   //=> 8
```

Ergo, you can create instances from a constructor delivered from a iif, in which private variables and functions are used.

Comment: you used a very small bit of processor to get your privacy...did you not?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify? What piece of code uses *a very small bit of processor*? In the assignment of `x` everything is assigned once. The constructor uses already assigned variables by closure. Wouldn't that be what you mean with efficient?